# How to create valid mail when running "User.create" from Rails 6 console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following Michael Hartl's tutorial and have an issue when I am trying to create a user in my `users` table.

When I run `User.create` from the Rails console I always get:

```
@messages={:email=>["is invalid"]}"
```

from `user.errors`.  Also my test fails:

```
FAIL["test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses",                                             #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f66146c67f0 @name="UserTest">, 0.05937384600110818]
 test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses#UserTest (0.06s)
        "lala@example.com" should be valid
```

I guess this is the issue, but I have no idea why.

Also this fails:

```
test "should be valid" do
  assert @user.valid?
end
```

If I write it like this the test passes:

```
test "should be valid" do
  assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

This fails also:

```
test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
  valid_addresses = %w[lala@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
  valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
    @user.email = valid_address
    assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
  end
end
```

If I write the test like this it passes:

```
test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
  valid_addresses = %w[lala@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                         first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
  valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
    @user.email = valid_address
    assert_not @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
  end
end
```

These are the Guard errors:

```
FAIL["test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f6614891a58 @name="UserTest">, 0.05828664900036529]
 test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses#UserTest (0.06s)
        "lala@example.com" should be valid
        test/models/user_test.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UserTest>'
        test/models/user_test.rb:37:in `each'
        test/models/user_test.rb:37:in `block in <class:UserTest>'

 FAIL["test_should_be_valid", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f6614859ab8 @name="UserTest">, 0.06591933299932862]
 test_should_be_valid#UserTest (0.07s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/models/user_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

This is my user_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.create(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[lala@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                         first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
  end


  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org
                          user.name@example. foo@bar_baz.com
                          foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end

  test "email address should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end

  test "password should present (nonblank)" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " * 5
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "password should have a minimum length" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end


end
```

This is my `user.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase}
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\-.]+\.[a-z]+/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255},
            format: { with: /VALID_EMAIL_REGEX/},
            uniqueness: false
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence:true, length: { minimum: 6}
end
```

Comment: try removing `/` and `/` from the `with:` option in you `validates` line, like `validates :email, ..., format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }`

Comment: Make sure you include in your question reproducible behavior, e.g., the exact command you are using with `User.create` including all arguments.

Comment: When testing individual validations DO NOT use assert @model.valid?. Its a huge anti-pattern that just invites false postives/negatives as .valid? is true if all the validations pass and false if any of them fail. Just because its in a book does not mean its a good idea. Instead you should call valid? to run the validations on the object and test the errors object for example `assert_includes("can't be blank", user.errors.messages[:name])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:format` validates the attributes' values by testing whether they match a given regular expression, which is specified using the `:with` option.

A [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) holds a regular expression, used to match a pattern against strings. Regexps are created using the `/.../`

Your regexp is `/VALID_EMAIL_REGEX/`. It means valid email must contain these symbols.

So your code means that `"VALID_EMAIL_REGEX@gmail.com"` is valid, but `"example@gmail.com"` is invalid.

In fact you have constant with regexp `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX`.

So you need to change your code to:

```
format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

(constant with regexp, not regexp)

By the way you don't need to write difficult regex for email. You can use regex from standard library:

```
format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot removing the /../ did the trick. and also fixed all the tests fails. i had be struggling  with this for 6 days now.